# How to get two different col from one select alias

Tags: mysql

I have below select sub query which have selected two columns but have only one alias how can i render both column individually to avoid run same query two times for two columns

`

```
(SELECT 
                `lp`.`base_price`, `lp`.`id`
            FROM
                `org_product_latest_prices` `lp`
            WHERE
                ((`lp`.`org_product_id` = `pr`.`org_product_id`)
                    AND (`lp`.`currency_code` = `pr`.`currency_code`)
                    AND (`lp`.`base_price` > 0)
                    AND (`lp`.`sell_organisation_id` = (SELECT 
                        `s`.`id`
                    FROM
                        (`organisations` `s`
                        LEFT JOIN `org_product_latest_prices` `p` ON ((`s`.`id` = `p`.`sell_organisation_id`)))
                    WHERE
                        ((`p`.`currency_code` = `pr`.`currency_code`)
                            AND (`s`.`org_type_code` = 'MFG')
                            AND (`p`.`org_product_id` = `pr`.`org_product_id`))
                    LIMIT 1))
                    AND (`lp`.`item_condition` = 'NEW'))
            LIMIT 1) AS `mfg_price``
```

Please Help
Thanks In Advance

Comment: The alias mfg_price is for the the sub query not for `lp`.`base_price`, `lp`.`id. if you wish to reference these in the main query then call them mfg_price.`base_price`, mfg_price.`id.?

Comment: But this subquery is just select statement of another query like

Comment: 'select subquery as mfg_price from table join another_table'